# What's the difference between action parameteres and view model, affecting routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have few actions within my controllers that are using parameteres.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetData(string id, string start, string end, string targetId)

public async Task<ActionResult> GetOtherData(string id, string start, string end)

.......
```

For this I had to make custom routes.

My questions:

What is the difference between using the action with parameters as above and using a ViewModel like this:

```
public class DataViewModel
{
     public string id { get; set; }
     public string start { get; set; }
     public string end { get; set; }
     public string targetId { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetData(DataViewModel model)
```

If I use a ViewModel as parameter to my action, do I still have to define a route for it or MVC will automatically understand it?

Currently having 4 routes it get's messy and probably I did it wrong because some routes are not matched correctly.

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ViewSingle",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{start}/{end}/{targetId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, start = UrlParameter.Optional, end = UrlParameter.Optional, targetId = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "OtherView",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{start}/{end}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, start = UrlParameter.Optional, end = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "View",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{y}/{m}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, y = UrlParameter.Optional, m = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );



        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Another thing is and maybe you can figure it from the Routes configuration above, I'm not sure if I understood routing correctly and how it should be done.

That's why I want to know if I can get rid of routing by using a ViewModel instead of parameters.

Another thing is if I use ViewModels, can I still share an url to a specific item? I think it won't work with ViewModels right?

Comment: No difference - both will work the same, so long as the model has only properties which are value types. Note also that only the last parameter in a route definition can be marked `UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Do I still need the route configuration then if I use a ViewModel? What about a direct url: `http://domain.com/controller/getdata?id=something&start=startdate&end=enddate&targetid=1`. Will this still work with a ViewModel in place and without routes? And why only the last parameter might be optional? I actually need all of them to be optional because if they are missing then the application will load some default ones.

Comment: You make them optional in the method (e.g. `int? targetId, DateTime? start` etc.), not in the route definition. Only the last one can be optional because if you only provided say 2 of the 4, then the route engine has no way of knowing which is which and you get the ugly query string rather that (say) `.../getdata/1/5`. Based on your model, all you need is the route with `name: "ViewSingle",` (and remove all the `UrlParameter.Optional`), then make you properties and the method parameters nullable)

Comment: One more thing: Is there any difference in the route between: `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{start}/{end}"` and `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{y}/{m}"` ?

Comment: And basically my route should look like this: `routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ViewSingle",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{start}/{end}/{targetId}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", targetId = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );` without defining start and end as optional right?

Comment: Yes they are different - in the first case your controller method needs parameters `int ID, DateTime start, DateTime end` and in the second case your method needs parameters `int ID, string y, string m` (or whatever your types are)

Comment: So I should have 2 different routes in that case right?

Comment: Yes, you would need 2 different routes